# Convert this date string to DATETIME or TIMESTAMP with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime

I'm using the Beanstream Payment API, and the response comes back with the following date format:

```
5/21/2013 3:51:28 PM
```

What would be the best way to convert this in order to store it as a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME in MySQL using PHP?

Comment: `strtotime($yourDateTimeString);` ? It'll give you a 10 digit integer. If you want a date, then just `date('date-format-here', strtotime($yourDateTimeString));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php), [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php), and [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) for how to parse, create, and format dates/times in PHP.

If you are in a hurry, this will work:

```
strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', strtotime('5/21/2013 3:51:28 PM'))
```